# Migrating PSQL table to jsonb without null values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have to migrate table which contains key and multiple values in columns(nullable) into jsonb represented key value postgres table.

```
K | V1 | V2 | V3  | V4
-----------------------
1 | a  | 42 |     | cde
```

I will probably need intermediate table to do it(can I do it without it?). But first challenge is to get the values correctly.
I've noticed that `json_agg` would give me something like

`{"K":1, "V1":"a", "V2":42, "V3":null, "V4":"cde"}`.

Instead, I would like to get something like

`{"V1":"a", "V2":42, "V4":"cde"}`

How can I filter out the fields out of jsonb?

And is there a way to get the migration done without intermediate table?

so the final thing I would like to have looks like this:

```
K | V
------------------------------------
1 | {"V1":"a", "V2":42, "V4":"cde"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t)),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) example:

```
with my_table(K, V1, V2, V3, V4) as (
values
    (1, 'a', 42, null, 'cde')
)

select k, jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t))- 'k' as jsonb_data
from my_table t;

 k |             jsonb_data             
---+------------------------------------
 1 | {"v1": "a", "v2": 42, "v4": "cde"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ah, cool. Didn't know that one ;) You should use `jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t)) - 'k'` to get the output fr3ak wants

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the row to a jsonb and remove the `k` key:

```
select k,jsonb_object_agg(key, val)
from (
  select k, 'v1' as key, v1 as val
  from t
  where v1 is not null
  union all
  select k, 'v2', v2::text
  from t
  where v2 is not null
  union all
  select k, 'v3', v3::text
  from t
  where v3 is not null
  union all
  select k, 'v4', v4
  from t
  where v4 is not null
) t
group by k
```

Comment: but nulls still stay there

Comment: @fr3ak: ah, missed that part. That makes it a bit more complicated